# What is the relation between $X^{(1)}$ of Gauss-Seidel and $X^{(1)}$ of Successive Over Relaxation if $X^{(0)}=0_{\mathbb{R^{n}}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's consider the matrix: $A$.

The matrix A can be rewritten as $A = D - L - U$.

$D$ is a diagonal matrix containing all the diagonal coefficients of the matrix $A$.

$L$ is the negation of the remaining lower triangular matrix.

$U$ is the negation of the remaining upper triangular matrix.

Now let's consider the system $AX=b$:
$$b= \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

According to the method of Gauss-Seider, we can decompose A as:

$$A = M - N = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
-\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

The iteration matrix of Gauss-Seider is given as the following:
$$B_{GS} = M^{-1}N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
M^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4}   & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, the construction will lead us to the following iterative method:

$$AX = b \implies X^{(k+1)} = M^{-1}NX^{(k)} + M^{-1}b$$
Let's take $X^{(0)} = \begin{pmatrix}  0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and calculate $X^{(1)}_{GS}$

$$X^{(1)}_{GS} = M^{-1}b=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4}   & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{4} \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, if we calculate the spectral radius of the iteration matrix of the Gauss-Seidel method, we will have: $\rho(B_{GS})=\frac{3}{4}$

$X^{(k+1)}=(\frac{1}{\omega} D - E)^{-1} (F-(1-\frac{1}{\omega}) D) X^{(k)} + (\frac{1}{\omega} D - E)^{-1} b$

Based on the spectral radius of $B_{GS}$, we can find the parameter $\omega_{0}$ related to the iteration matrix of the Successive Over-Relaxation which gives the fastest convergence like the following.

$$\omega_{0} = \frac{2}{1+ \sqrt{1-\frac{3}{4}}}$$
$$\omega_{0}=\frac{4}{3}$$
$$\rho(B_{\omega_0}) = \omega_0 - 1 = \frac{1}{3}$$
$B_{\omega_0}$ is the iteration matrix of the SOR method with the optimal $\omega$.

The required is to find the $X^{(1)}_{SOR}$ of the SOR method without calculating $B_{w_{0}=\frac{3}{4}}$the iteration matrix of the SOR method given $X^{(1)}_{GS}$ obtained from the first iteration of the Gauss-Seidel method.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is to write $X^{(1)}_{SOR}$ in terms of the $X^{(1)}_{GS}$.

If we take $X^{(0)} = 0_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}$, then we will have:

$$X^{(1)}_{SOR} = (\frac{1}{\omega_{0}}D-E)^{-1}b = ((\frac{1}{\omega_{0}} +\frac{\omega_{0}-1}{\omega_{0}} -\frac{\omega_{0}-1}{\omega_{0}})D-E)^{-1}b \\
=((1 -\frac{\omega_{0}-1}{\omega_{0}})D-E)^{-1}b \\
= (D-E)^{-1}b - \frac{\omega_{0}-1}{\omega_{0}} D^{-1}b \\
= X^{(1)}_{GS} - \frac{\omega_{0}-1}{\omega_{0}} D^{-1}b
$$

Replacing $\omega_{0}$ by its value $(\omega_{0}=\frac{4}{3})$, we get:

$$X^{(1)}_{SOR}=X^{(1)}_{GS} - \frac{\frac{4}{3}-1}{\frac{4}{3}} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & & \\ & \frac{1}{2} & \\ & & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\ 
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{4} \end{pmatrix}
- \frac{1}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \\
=\begin{pmatrix} 1-\frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} \\
\end{pmatrix} \\ 
X^{(1)}_{SOR}= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{8} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$